# LinkedIn Sharing Oauth 2 with Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, linkedin-api

I have tried with following:

https://github.com/dongri/OAuthSwift

With that authenticate user properly, while getting following error message from server on sharing:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=400 "HTTP Status 400: Bad Request, Response: {
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Couldn&#39;t parse share document: error: Unexpected end of file after null",
  "requestId": "3TYEC50Y29",
  "status": 400,
  "timestamp": 1436863874989
}"
```

Here is how I pass the parameter to HTTP body:

```
let theJSONData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(
                parameters ,
                options: NSJSONWritingOptions(0),
                error: nil)
let theJSONText = NSString(data: theJSONData!,
                encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
var bodyData : NSData = theJSONText!.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!
request.HTTPBody = bodyData
```

Already checked theJSONText is valid JSON. Also I am unable to keep maintain session with that. I need to login every time I am trying to share.